# Sorting records by attribute in shapefile using PyShp

Tags: python, shapefile, features, sorting, pyshp

I know how to get records in a shapefile using PyShp, but how to sort records by an attribute (i.e., `"NAME"` or `"POPULATION"`)?

My code:

```py
import shapefile

file = "c:/data/cities.shp"

with shapefile.Reader(file) as shape_file:
    feats = shape_file.shapeRecords()

for feat in feats:
    print(feat)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The script you need:

```py
features = shapefile.Reader("c:/data/cities.shp").shapeRecords()
features.sort(key=lambda feat: feat.record["NAME"]) # or ["POPULATION"]
```

`shapeRecords` returns a list of `ShapeRecord` objects (all features). A `ShapeRecord` object has `record` and `shape` properties which return a list of the attributes value and a shape (geometry), respectively. Therefore, you can use the following script to sort the features by a specific attribute/column.

```py
import shapefile

file = "c:/data/cities.shp"
shape_file = shapefile.Reader(file)
features = shape_file.shapeRecords()

print("initial order of the features:")
for feat in features:
    print(feat.record["NAME"])


### sort features by an attribute ###
features.sort(key=lambda feat: feat.record["NAME"]) # or ["POPULATION"]

print("\nsorted features:")
for feat in features:
    print(feat.record["NAME"])

shape_file.close()
```

Output:

```
initial order of the features:
B
C
A

sorted features:
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend working with [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/index.html) to manipulate your attributes (and vector data). You can use the [`sort_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-values) method to sort your attributes by a column such as `"NAME"` or `"POPULATION"`. For example:

```py
import geopandas as gpd

shp = 'c:/data/cities.shp'
gdf = gpd.read_file(shp) # Read shapefile as geodataframe

sorted_gdf = gdf.sort_values('NAME') # Sort by NAME column
```

---

```
gdf
Out[2]: 
     id         NAME  POPULATION                        geometry
0  None     New York     8419000  POINT (698736.959 5291848.602)
1  None     Portland      645291  POINT (699306.170 5291870.891)
2  None     St. Paul      304547  POINT (698724.101 5291368.545)
3  None  Minneapolis      420324  POINT (699291.597 5291356.544)
4  None       Austin      950807  POINT (698992.419 5291640.292)

sorted_gdf
Out[3]: 
     id         NAME  POPULATION                        geometry
4  None       Austin      950807  POINT (698992.419 5291640.292)
3  None  Minneapolis      420324  POINT (699291.597 5291356.544)
0  None     New York     8419000  POINT (698736.959 5291848.602)
1  None     Portland      645291  POINT (699306.170 5291870.891)
2  None     St. Paul      304547  POINT (698724.101 5291368.545)
```